# How to make nosetests use dotted syntax?

Tags: python, nose

Is there a way to make [nosetests](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) print:

```
ERROR: product.test.lib.test_csv_tools:CSVToolsTest.test_missing_header_csv
```

instead of:

```
ERROR: test_missing_header_csv (product.test.lib.test_csv_tools.CSVToolsTest)
```

Then I could easily copy it and run the single test(s) that failed. Would be quite handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be looking [for a specific nose plugin](https://nose-plugins.jottit.com/) that provides this kind of output. For example, the [`nose_runnable_test_names`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose_runnable_test_names) sounds close to what you are asking about.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Wondering why that's not the default. Will accept in 6 minutes (SO restriction).